# Spring batch stop the ItemReader running when app starts

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch to run jobs which are triggered from a controller method. Everything works fine except when the application first boots the `ItemReader` runs and reads through everything.

Is this expected behaviour? It's not really a big deal it just slows down the boot time by a good 500 seconds.

Note: The job itself isn't running as I've disabled that via

```
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: false
```

**Edit:**

Configuration

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfiguration {

    @Value("${app.directoryPath}")
    public String directoryPath;

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private final LocationRepository locationRepository;

    private final VideoRepository videoRepository;

    public JobConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, LocationRepository locationRepository, VideoRepository videoRepository) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
        this.locationRepository = locationRepository;
        this.videoRepository = videoRepository;
    }

    @Bean(name = "importVideo")
    public Job importVideo(Step processVideos) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("importVideo")
                .start(processVideos)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "processVideos")
    public Step processVideos(VideoItemReader videoItemReader, VideoProcessor videoProcessor, VideoWriter videoWriter) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("processVideos").<File, Video>chunk(25)
                .reader(videoItemReader)
                .processor(videoProcessor)
                .writer(videoWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public VideoWriter videoWriter() {
        return new VideoWriter(videoRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public VideoProcessor videoProcessor() {
        return new VideoProcessor(locationRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public VideoItemReader videoItemReader() {
        return new VideoItemReader("file:" + directoryPath, locationRepository);
    }
}
```

And I'm calling the job with a `GET` request via

```
@GetMapping("/jobs/{job}")
public ResponseEntity<String> importVideos(@PathVariable String job) {

    if (job.equalsIgnoreCase("createThumbnails")) {
        executeJob(createThumbnails);
    } else if (job.equalsIgnoreCase("importVideo")) {
        executeJob(importVideo);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>("running", HttpStatus.OK);
}

private void executeJob(Job job) {
    Set<JobExecution> runningJobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(job.getName());

    if (runningJobExecutions.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        log.info("executeJob already running, so... NOPE!");
    }
}
```

But how I'm calling it has nothing to do with it, if I delete that code the same behaviour still exists...

Comment: can you post your code like how you've configured your job and how you are calling it.

Comment: Sure, I'm positive it has nothing to do with how the job is being called, but is there something in the configuration that tells SB to run the readers on boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my issue, the problem was my custom reader implementation was also implementing `InitializingBean` where it was calling what was effectively 'getVideos()'.

Removing the `InitializingBean` interface stopped the reader running on each boot.

Answer (score 0):

This would be mostly due to spring not recognising spring.batch.job.enabled property, please try adding this in your

Load your property explicitly in your Application class, hopefully this will solve the issue.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:batch.properties")
```

Comment: If this was the case, surely the job would be running, which it's not.